# Change MySQL select round query to Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

How to change this query to `Laravel 5.5`

```
"SELECT ROUND((COUNT(STATUS)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data_ap))*100,1)
 FROM data_ap WHERE STATUS LIKE '%UP%'";
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like that :

```
\DB::table('data_ap')
  ->select(\DB::raw('ROUND((COUNT(STATUS)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data_ap))*100,1) as calc'))
  ->where('STATUS','like','%UP%')
  ->get();
```

Comment: i have the result like this [{"calc":"100.0"}] % ...how if i just get result 100.0 %

Answer (score 0):

I think you must keep native query with `Raw Expressions`, for more here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#raw-expressions

Answer (score 0):

@Muhammad Anwari: You can simply point the targeted column/alias

```
\DB::table('data_ap')
   ->select(\DB::raw('ROUND((COUNT(STATUS)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data_ap))*100,1) as calc'))
   ->where('STATUS','like','%UP%')
   ->first()->calc;
```